# Do email clients mess up identifiers in links?

Tags: html-email, email

Through our platform I'm sending automatic emails with an unsubscribe link.

The unsubscribe has the following format:

`http://example.com/unsubscribe?id={id}&c={code}`

The Id represents the UserId in the database, the Code is just some hash that is linked to the User (so people can't unsubscribe random people).

Problem is that I'm getting exceptions that **the UserId does not match the database** (about 5-10%) - the Id is just way larger then the largest Id in our database.

Another weird thing is that the **query parameters seem to be reversed**. It is suddenly `?c={code}&id={id}` instead of `?id={id}&c={code}`.

The code is *really really* simple, and I can't believe there is anything that can go wrong in constructing the original message. In a way there don't seem to be any other code paths.

I can come up with two *possible* causes:

- Some email tools mangle the url as some kind of anti spam / phishing / tracking / footprinting?
- This is somehow related to character encoding going bad or something similar?

But in a way I have no clue and I'm really at a loss here. I really would like to fix this, because the last thing I want to do is spam people by accident that can't unsubscribe.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: From personal experience, when I get an email with GET style parameters, various MUA don't hyperlink it properly and I must carefully copy and paste it. This copy & paste requirement may be causing the failures you're seeing.  I urge you to use slug style for maximum portability: `http://example.com/unsubscribe/{id}/{code}/`

Comment: Thanks that is a smart idea! I'm going to try out if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi @bishop, do you btw have a specific MUA that does this? It will help me hopefully to debug this for sure and try to understand the specific problem.

Comment: Depends really on the URL complexity.  I've seen it variously in SquirrelMail, Thunderbird, Claws, and Sylpheed.  Recommendation: when your code detects a problem around the url, record the User-Agent.  You may start to see a pattern.

Comment: Ok thanks! I do have the UserAgent, but it seems to be plain vanilla IE9 `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)`.

Comment: Those might be generic web mail clients then, rather than dedicated clients which usually send [a distinctive UA](https://udger.com/resources/ua-list#Email%20client).  If that's true, then I'd ensure you're sending simple HTML in your emails.